# IIS doing unexpected redirect

Tags: iis, http-redirect

I have website abc.com and abc.co.in.I have two webservers also.
The following issue happens only in abc.co.in with same application deployed on same.
We have written a custom IHttpModule and do a rewrite to abc.co.in?some=data.

Expected behavior: When user enters some.abc.co.in the expected behavior is browser still display some.abc.co.in but internally call abc.co.in?some=data
Actual behavior: The page is rendered properly but in browser the URL changes to some.abc.co.in?some=data

I checked what is happening
1.First the server receives the request and does a 301 redirect.
2.The redirect location is some.abc.co.in?some=data

I am stuck in this for a day and critical to fix to make our site up and running.
How to debug this issue further ?.Any one can think of possible cause?

ETW Trace shows

```
<ApplicationData>
<TraceData>
<DataItem>
<OldUrl>/</OldUrl>
<NewUrl>/fp?&id=hazzel&params=</NewUrl>
</DataItem>
</TraceData>
</ApplicationData>


<ApplicationData>
<TraceData>
<DataItem>
<ModuleName>DefaultDocumentModule</ModuleName>
<Notification>128</Notification>
<HttpStatus>301</HttpStatus>
<HttpReason>Moved Permanently</HttpReason>
</DataItem>
</TraceData>
</ApplicationData>


<ApplicationData>
<TraceData>
<DataItem>
<Headers>Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Location: http://some.abc.co.in/fp/?id=data
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
</Headers>
</DataItem>
</TraceData>
</ApplicationData>
```

Answer (score 0):

One more update is I have
Application
-Subapplication1
-Subapplication2
I trying to rewrite from Application to Subapplication and instead of rewrite redirect with 301 is happening. After the redirect it works but the url in browsers is changing because of 301.